# JPA replace 1:M set for an entity

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Alert implements Serializable {
    private long alertId;
    private Set<AlertTime> alertTimes = new HashSet<AlertTime>(0);

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<AlertTime> getAlertTimes() {
        return alertTimes;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class AlertTime implements Serializable {
    private long alertTimeId;
    private Date time;
    private Alert alert;

    @ManyToOne
    public Alert getAlert() {
        return this.alert;
    }
```

When I need to update `Alert` there may be a different number of `AlertTime`s, so I'm trying to merge `Alert` and remove the `AlertTime`s and persist new ones. The problem with this is that there's a unique index on (AlertTime.alertTimeId, AlertTime.time) and when I try to remove and then persist within the same transaction the SQL insert happens before the delete, which violates the constraint. I could delete the `AlertTime`s entities in a separate transaction, but I'd like it all to be in one transaction so I can rollback all changes if an exception occurs when calling a back-end web service.

Is there a better method to be able to change the `Alert` entity's `alertTimes`? Or, is it possible to at least force the SQL delete before the insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flush the context with `em.flush()` after removing `AlertTime`s to ensure that `delete` statements was issued.

Also it can be better to configure orphan removal for `alertTimes`, to delete `AlertTime`s from the database by removing them from the collection, without explicit `remove()` calls. In JPA 2.0 use `@OneToMany(..., orphanRemoval = true)`. Though it still would require `flush()`.

Comment: Doesn't flush commit to the DB, so I couldn't rollback the changes made before flush() was called?  I've got it working using your solution, thanks.

Comment: @ravun: No, flush doesn't do anything with transactions.